# What do you call writing in memory of someone who has passed away?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I was recently invited to contribute a piece of writing to commemorate a friend who has passed away. My writing, along with others, were compiled into a book that was passed out at the funeral; these were memorial tributes "in memoriam" of my friend, some prose and some poetry, but certainly not "obituaries." Is there a better word or phrase to refer to this type of writing than "[eulogy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eulogy)," which, as far as I know, generally refers to a praise-filled speech?

> **Eulogy**: A speech or piece of writing that praises someone or something highly,
>   especially a tribute to someone who has just died (Source: Oxford Dictionaries)

EDIT: These writings range in tone from elegiac to eulogizing, which is why I hesitate to use the word "eulogy" as a blanket term.

Comment: Memorials? Memoria?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are speaking of an ***[elegy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elegy)***, or ***elegiac*** writings:

> a sad poem or song : a poem or song that expresses sorrow for someone who is dead

[Merriam-Webster]

Also consider [**lamentation**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lamentation):

> an expression of great sorrow or deep sadness

[Merriam-Webster]

If you were attempting to find a word that fits all of these different types of writings, you might generally classify them as ***[commemorative](http://intended%20to%20honor%20an%20important%20event%20or%20person%20from%20the%20past)***:

> intended to honor an important event or person from the past

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: The OP said they did not want to call it elegiac or elegies.

Comment: Elegy and eulogy are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Commemorative is best. It is like a small biography. I am writing several paragraphs about my mother's life as a handout. I like this term better than eulogy for this. Her life speaks for itself.

Comment: Yes. The word "commemorative" certainly used to exist as a noun, but the most recent example the OED has is from the seventeenth century *1649   F. Roberts Clavis Bibliorum (ed. 2) 31   A Commemorative of that wonderfull deliverance.
1669   T. Gale Court of Gentiles: Pt. I ii. viii. 110   Commemoratives of some Divine presence.* Are you aware of people speaking of such tributes as "commemoratives", or of "writing a commemorative"?

Comment: @WS2: Googling *"a commemorative for"* shows that *"commemorative"* as a noun is still very much in use for stamps and coins, and is occasionally used for other artwork. I think it sounds fine, although *elegy* might be better for a piece of writing or music.

Comment: @PeterShor I usually see "commemorative" used as an adjective in the context of coins and stamps as in [The Royal Mint has issued a commemorative coin honouring Stephen Hawking](https://www.livescience.com/64981-stephen-hawking-black-hole-coin.html). Numismatists and philatlelists refer to "commemoratives" because, in their contexts coins and stamps can be assumed; a coin collectors' magazine might talk about "the Stephen Hawking 50p commemorative" for example. However to me this still sounds like  an adjective, merely with the noun elided.

Answer (score 1):

> piece of writing

I'd say it counts as a collection of Eulogies.

Answer (score 1):

The **book of condolence(s)**, also called "condolence register", contains **condolence messages**.

> Condolence definition (*Cambridge dictionaries online*): ​sympathy and
>   ​sadness for the ​family or ​close ​friends of a ​person who has
>   ​recently ​died, or an ​expression of this, ​especially in written
>   ​form.